# Fetching sensitive data from application.conf

Tags: java, gradle, application.conf

I am trying to understand someone else´s Gradle project and need some help in understanding the syntax. In `resources->application.conf` there is configuration for username and password written this way:

```
login{
    username = ${?USERNAME}
    password = ${?PASSWORD}
}
```

Where does that syntax mean and where do I get the values of username and password? I am currently using intelliJ IDEA. If I know the values of sensitive data, is there anyway I can save these values without exposing them in the code?

Thanks.

Comment: For similar things while working with java I rather prefer to use a custom properties file. The application at opening check if the file exists and eventually prompt the user for credentials and save them. To get an insight about Java syntax for reading and writing a properties file you can see this link: 
https://www.codejava.net/coding/reading-and-writing-configuration-for-java-application-using-properties-class#CreateProperties
I also usually add any obfuscation/ bidirectional encryption function so that the username and password you can read by opening the property file cannot be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a system property, so the actual value would be determined at runtime from a property (e.g. passing `-DUSERNAME=zimmer` in a run script).

The way you could save them would be to have your run script pass the property, if you don't want to specify it manually every time.

Environment variables would be accessed with `$System.env.USERNAME` style, so my earlier answer assumed that it would search both system properties and env variables.

Comment: How do you know that these are environment variables? The filename `application.conf` is so generic, it could be anything.

Comment: @RolandIllig well the filename is irrelevant, but you're right about Gradle not doing a direct search down to environment variables...

Answer (score 0):

Those are just placeholders which are being substituted when devops deploy the application. Usually used to hide sensitive information like username, password or secret keys. Also used to rotate sensitive information at a specific period of time.